# How does GET_LOCK(‘lockname’, 0) of MariaDB/MySQL work?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have found the use of `GET_LOCK(‘lockname’, 0)` of MariaDB in a java application that I am working on.

The timeout value is used as 0 here. It should work in non-blocking fashion, I suppose. But, after getting some exceptions in the log file, I have got the impression that it is still trying the get the lock using a default timeout time. Applying the call of `IS_FREE_LOCK(‘lockname’)` before  `GET_LOCK` call makes the application run smoothly.

My question is, what is the impact of using 0 as the timeout value here?

Comment: Note that using `GET_LOCK` isn't a great practice. Usually you can achieve a much less blocked code using transactions or better code structure. `GET_LOCK` isn't supported in Galera if you ever get to the stage of scaling your application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you determined the timeout?. I can't reproduce the problem from the command line:

Session 1:

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT GET_LOCK('lock1', 10);
+-----------------------+
| GET_LOCK('lock1', 10) |
+-----------------------+
|                     1 |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Session 2:

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT GET_LOCK('lock1', 0.5);
+------------------------+
| GET_LOCK('lock1', 0.5) |
+------------------------+
|                      0 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.500 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT GET_LOCK('lock1', 0);
+----------------------+
| GET_LOCK('lock1', 0) |
+----------------------+
|                    0 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: The scenario I am using is to use it from two Java clients concurrently, I have got so many exceptions in the log file like the following: _`java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; `_  
In the application code, if GET_LOCK('lock1', 0) returns zero, the update query should not have executed. I suspect, GET_LOCK('lock1', 0) tries to continue to get the lock even if the timeout value is set to zero. The issue is fixed by applying IS_FREE_LOCK('lock1') call before GET_LOCK('lock1', 0) call. But I initially expected GET_LOCK call by using zero timeout would be sufficient here.

Comment: the JDBC batch is not using GET_LOCK(), you're probably getting MySQL Error Code: 1205. "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"

Answer (score 0):

"lock wait timeout" has nothing to do with `GET_LOCK`.  It only applies to InnoDB transactions.  The default for `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` is 50 seconds.  (In my opinion, that is much too high.)

InnoDB transactions should be designed to finish in very few seconds.  Never keep a transaction open while waiting for user interaction; a potty break could lead to "lock wait timeout".

I see that it is a "BatchUpdate".  Is this loading a lot of data?  Is it coming from some slow source?  Could you use autocommit and not put the entire load into a single transaction?

Another thing...  If you start a transaction (`BEGIN` or `START TRANSACTION`), *then* do `GET_LOCK('foo', 51)`, and 'foo' is not available, you are asking for "wait lock timeout".

Please provide the bigger picture (BatchUpdate, reason for GET_LOCK, etc) so we can dig deeper.